# How to rename an xml node to a html tag

Tags: java, html, xml

Say I have a Java String which has xml data like so:

```
String content = "<abc> Hello <mark> World </mark> </abc>";
```

Now, I seek to render this String as text on a web page and hightlight/mark the word "World". The tag "abc" could change dynamically, so is there a way I can rename the outermost xml tag in a String using Java ?

I would like to convert the above String to the format shown below:

```
String content = "<i> Hello <mark> World </mark> </i>";
```

Now, I could use the new String to set html content and display the text in italics and highlight the word World.

Thanks,
Sony

PS: I am using xquery over files in BaseX xml database. The String content is essentially a result of an xquery which uses ft:extract(), a function to extract full text search results.

Comment: Can't you have your xquery return actual xml objects? Then you don't need to re-parse it and can use DOM methods directly, or an implementation of javax.xml.transform.

Comment: I agree with @OrangeDog. If you use XQuery over an XML tree, there should be no need for convert the result tree to a string (I guess that is what your `ft:extract()` extension is doing) and then reparsing for transformation... All this can be done in one XQuery query. Also, here there is no XQuery part after the string is built. Retagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML "parsing" with regexes can be cumbersome. If there is a possibility that your XML string can be more complicated than the one used in your example, you should consider processing it as a real XML node.

```
String newName = "i";
// parse String as DOM
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(content)));

// modify DOM
doc.renameNode(doc.getDocumentElement(), null, newName);
```

This code assumes that the element to that needs to be renamed is always the outermost element, that is, the root element.

Now the document is a DOM tree. It can be converted back to String object with a transformer.

```
// output DOM as String
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
String italicsContent = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple regex?

```
    String content = "<abc> Sample text <mark> content </mark> </abc>";
    Pattern outerTags = Pattern.compile("^<(\\w+)>(.*)</\\1>$");
    Matcher m = outerTags.matcher(content);
    if (m.matches()) {
        content = "<i>" + m.group(2) + "</i>";
        System.out.println(content);
    }
```

Alternatively, use a DOM parser, find the children of the outer tag and print them, preceded and followed by your desired tag as strings